# Apache vhost - How to do?

Tags: server, apache2, webserver

I have no idea how vhost works.

But what I want to accomplish is that my webmin url becomes conf.mydomain.se instead of conf.mydomain.se:10000

I have other urls to this server but I want to just ignore that and solve this and maybe I can learn how to the rest by doing that :)

```
    <VirtualHost conf.mydomain.se:8001>
        ServerName 185.xx.xx.25
    </VirtualHost>
```

At the moment my conf looks like the above.

If I get a working example of how to solve my problem then I might understand this.

Comment: this is about the apache webserver and makes no mention of ubuntu or using ubuntu packages of the webserver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so i found the problem after a while.
It was both what i wrote here but mostly not disable default conf

The working one is belov

```
<VirtualHost _default_>

  ServerName conf.mydomain.se
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8001/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8001/

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `conf.mydomain.se:10000` 10000 says the port which is running your server. Default port is for **Http** is **80** . When you type url in browser it automatically request 80 port in the server (for https default port is 443). You just need to add `80` instead of `8001` in your current configuration. Make sure 80 port is allowed by firewall if didn't work.
Then just typing `conf.mydomain.se` will work.